# mysql match against exact phrase doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm trying to find an exact phrase but for some reason, it finds matches with additional words , here is the code :

```
$subLocationId = DB::select( 

DB::raw(' SELECT id  FROM sub_location WHERE match(sub_location_name) against("' .
    $subLocationName . '" IN BOOLEAN MODE ) ' )

);
```

above is Laravel ORM query , and here is regular mysql:

```
' SELECT id  FROM sub_location WHERE match(sub_location_name) 
  against("' .$subLocationName . '" IN BOOLEAN MODE ) '
```

I input : "Business Bay" but it matches "53 Business Bay" , I'd like it to match only "Business Bay" without any extra word from front or behind

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use

```
$subLocationId = DB::select( 
  DB::raw("SELECT id  FROM sub_location sub_location_name='" . $subLocationName. "'" )

);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it with the following query:

```
\DB::table('sub_location')
  ->select(['id'])
  ->where('sub_location_name', $subLocationName);
```